# Spring Boot 2.4.2 - DNS Resolution Problem at start on Apple M1

Tags: java, spring-boot, dns

I'm upgrading my Spring Boot version from `2.1.x` to `2.4.2`. When I compiled and run the code, I got the following warning:

```
Unable to load io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider,fallback to system defaults. This may result in incorrect DNS resolutions on MacOS.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider
```

When I deploy the project to DEV environment which is in AWS and CentOS machine, there is no such warning message in the logs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 25):

I needed a version in addition to classifier:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <classifier>osx-x86_64</classifier>
        <version>4.1.59.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

scope is optional but classifier is required.

For the latest version, see:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-resolver-dns-native-macos

Example: Latest version for M1 macs (aarch_64), as of 2022-01:

```
<classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
<version>4.1.72.Final</version>
```

Comment: Where can I find the classifier information on my Mac? I have a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021) with Apple M1 Pro chip.

Comment: @myverdict As in the example above, M1 chips use "osx-aarch_64".

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, but it doesn't seem right that we need to add a dependency to work around something.

Answer (score 14):

**Gradle** **syntax** if you prefer:

```
compile "io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:4.1.72.Final:osx-x86_64"
```

and for ARM-based macbook:

```
compile "io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:4.1.72.Final:osx-aarch_64"
```

Answer (score 13):

For this pull request https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/10848, the log level changes from "debug" to "warn."

To solve this problem, you can add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 7):

It will mostly occur during local development on macOS with Apple Silicon as discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/11020).

If you are using Maven then adding the following under the `project` tag in `pom.xml` should solve the issue:

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>macos-m1</id>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <family>mac</family>
        <arch>aarch64</arch>
      </os>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
        <classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

This ensures the profile is only activated for macOS with ARM64.

Answer (score 6):

If you have Gradle and want to include netty only locally you can make use of https://github.com/google/osdetector-gradle-plugin

```
plugins {
    id("com.google.osdetector") version "1.7.0"
}

dependencies {
    if (osdetector.arch.equals("aarch_64")) {
        implementation("io.netty:netty-all")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/11020), add the following dependency in your module.

```
<properties>
  <version.netty>4.1.59.Final</version.netty>
</properties>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
  <version>${version.netty}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  <classifier>osx-x86_64</classifier>
</dependency>
```

If you face this issue only while running your app locally on macOS, you may add the dependency for a specific maven profile, e.g. "local".

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>local</id>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
        <version>${version.netty}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <classifier>osx-x86_64</classifier>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

You can avoid specifying `version` if you import [netty-bom](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-bom) in `dependencyManagement`.

Comment: This no longer appears to solve the issue

Answer (score 3):

This one is working on my MacBook Pro M1 Pro

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.72.Final</version>
                <classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
</dependency>
```

it works for me on my M1 pro

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Intellij and gradle try File->invalidate caches

```
implementation("io.netty:netty-all:4.1.75.Final")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are facing this issue in your local Apple M1/M2, and if you don't want to add any additional dependencies then you can use this below solution:

Step 1)Download any IntelX64 based JDK distribution.

Sample download source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/download(In my case, I was using jdk11 hence I downloaded `microsoft-jdk-11.0.20-macOS-x64.tar.gz` from this page)

Step 2)Set your java to this new jdk from your IDE(Intellij Idea for my case)

This worked like a charm for me