# Encountered "no netty_resolver_dns_native_macos_x86_64 in java.library.path" when attempting use Spring Webflux WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, netty, spring-webclient

as per the title above.

Been getting this error:

```
00:41:21.549 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - Unable to load the library 'netty_resolver_dns_native_macos_x86_64', trying other loading mechanism.
```

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_resolver_dns_native_macos_x86_64 in java.library.path:

While trying to test out WebClient as a replacement for RestTemplate.

What I've tried:

1. Excluding Netty from the spring-boot-starter-webflux dependency and adding spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty as an explicit dependency.
2. Adding netty-resolver-dns-native-macos as a dependency.

Neither seems to work.

Using spring boot parent 2.4.2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you add the full debug log ?

Comment: Are you perhaps on Apple Silicon?  I get this error with netty when running on M1, but afaik netty falls back to the non-native dns resolver and is just a bit slower.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot 2.4.2 - DNS Resolution Problem at start on Apple M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65954571/spring-boot-2-4-2-dns-resolution-problem-at-start-on-apple-m1)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.79.Final</version>
        <classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Depends on the OS arch you may need different classifier, for me worked `<classifier>osx-x86_64</classifier>`